# Microsoft Office tracking license marks/keys in saved files (doc/docx/xls etc.)?

Tags: microsoft-office, privacy, license

Does Microsoft Office use any marks/keys in saved files, that can track the computer and software license using which file was saved?

E.g.: I use Office at work and save files on pendrive. When I'm home I recall to check something and introduce little modifications. I'd save this file using MS Office Home and Student license, but at work I will be redistributing this file and it should look as it was saved at work, with company's license (not my private).

Will saving it at work once again wipe license marks from home (if any exist)?

Comment: If this is Office 2010 you can see for yourself exactly what it does or doesn't save. Just put a `.zip` extension on the end of `.docx` and open it in your favourite archive utility.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft does not record what edition of its software was used to save a file, except for the version information. In other words, Word 2010 vs Word 2007, to ensure compatibility.

But as Mark said in his comment, you can simply unzip a `.docx` file and see for yourself. It's just a compressed folder consisting largely of XML.

Answer (score 1):

To remove all personal information from Office documents (which do *not* include licensing information or machine details BTW), in Windows 7 and later (possibly in Vista as well) you can check the file's Properties in Windows Explorer and click on the *Remove Properties and Personal Information* link on the Details tab (See http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows7/Change-the-properties-for-a-file for more).

If you're even more paranoid, follow the instructions on removing any other hidden data:

For Office 2007: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/remove-hidden-data-and-personal-information-from-office-documents-HA010037593.aspx

For Office 2010/2013:

- http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/remove-hidden-data-and-personal-information-by-inspecting-documents-HA010354329.aspx
- http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/remove-hidden-data-and-personal-information-by-inspecting-presentations-HA010354330.aspx
- http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/remove-hidden-data-and-personal-information-by-inspecting-workbooks-HA010354331.aspx